# Backup error: Failed to flush the commit table to disk

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, backup

When I try to backup a SQL Server 2008 database, I receive an error:

```
Backup failed for Server 'SQL2008TEST'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)
Failed to flush the commit table to disk in dbid 32 due to error 2601.
```

Does anybody know the cause of this error?

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when you have enabled change tracking on the database. A fix was released some time back:

[FIX: Backup fails in SQL Server 2008, SQL Server 2008 R2, or SQL Server 2012 if you enable change tracking on the database](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2603910) (Microsoft Support)

As it says there:

> The fix [...] was first released in Cumulative Update 7 for SQL Server 2008 Service Pack 2

The latest (and final) Service Pack 4 for SQL Server 2008 would also contain this fix.